# How do I conditionally set active state in category navigation?

Tags: templating, categories, conditional

Here is the code I am trying to use to set an active state for category navigation:

```
    {% for category in categories %}
        <li {% if craft.request.segment(2) == "{{ category.slug }}" %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}﻿
```

It seems that the conditional can't check against the category.slug output. Is this the case? What would be a better approach?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the quotes or braces in twig tags to reference variables.

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <li {% if craft.request.segment(2) == category.slug %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}﻿
```

You could also use ternary operators:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <li {{ craft.request.segment(2) == category.slug ? 'class="active"' : "" }}><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}﻿
```

Comment: What if I wanted to set class based on the url having no segment 2?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could try using twig's default filter: `craft.request.segment(2)|default("")`

Comment: Actually, I guessed and answered my own follow up by replacing "category.slug" with "null" to set class when no category is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Small update for Craft3 in the syntax :

```
{% set categories = craft.categories().all() %}
{% nav category in categories %}
    <li class="nav-menu-item {{ craft.app.request.getSegment(2) == category.slug ? 'nav-menu-item-current' : '' }}{% endif %}">
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

PS. Is there any other way to achieve this ? Going through craft.app is apparently frowned upon : https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/templating/global-variables.html#craft-app

Answer (score 1):

I use the current `entry` as something to compare against, instead of the `craft.app.request….` Also one can also use the id instead of the slug. So here, based on the previous examples a little variation:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories().all() %}
{% nav category in categories %}
    <li class="nav-menu-item {{ entry.id == category.id ? 'nav-menu-item-current' : '' }}{% endif %}">
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

Example untested. Please correct me, if wrong.